# How to apply a function to a value using the (var1)(var2) notation in python

Tags: python, function

I am solving a couple of problems in python
In one of them, its asks me to write a function such that when
`examplefunction([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)` returns something lets just say `10`.

The trouble is, I've never seen notation using double `()()` to call a function so far in python.

I've tried looking at multiple posts on stack overflow such as 
[Python: Apply function to values in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935232/python-apply-function-to-values-in-nested-dictionary)

But there is really no question like this.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered in a concrete way.  The simple answer is that you need `examplefunction` to return a function.  Don't think of it as "double ()()".  It is one () that returns a value.  That value is a function, which is then called with the second ().

Comment: `()()` doesn't call *a* function.

Comment: @chepner I'd say it might. If the function returns itself, then that calls *a* function (twice).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`object()()` is just `_result = object()` and `_result()` chained. As long as the first call returns a callable object, the second call expression can proceed.

Have your `examplefunction()` call return another function. Functions are objects too, so you could just return an existing function:

```
def examplefunction():
    return secondfunction

def secondfunction():
    return 10
```

at which point `examplefunction()()` produces `10`.

You can also have your `examplefunction()` call produce a new function object each time, by defining that function object as part of its body:

```
def examplefunction():
    def nestedfunction():
        return 10
    return nestedfunction
```

This gives the same result, but the added advantage that `nestedfunction()` has (read) access to all local names defined in `examplefunction` (these are called *closures*); this allows you to parameterise how `nestedfunction()` behaves:

```
def examplefunction(base):
    def nestedfunction():
        return base * 2
    return nestedfunction

examplefunction(5)()  # produces 10
```

I suspect that your assignment is trying to teach you these principles.

Answer (score 2):

Functions don't have multiple parameter brackets. Those are just referring to nested functions, or functions that incorporate other functions.

For example:

```
def func(a):
    def func2(b):
        return a + b
    return func2
```

Would be invoked like this:

```
func(1)(2)
```

(and would return `3` as an answer)

So it appears there are two parameter brackets, but really they are for two different functions!

Hope it helps!

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874825/python-functions-with-multiple-parameter-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

If you see `(...)(...)` it means that function calls are chained and the first function returns another function.

Example:

```
def fn1(val1):
    def fn2(val2):
        print("{} {}".format(val1, val2))
    return fn2

fn1("Hello")("World") # -> "Hello World"

# you can also write this as:
var1 = fn1("Hello")
var1("World")
```