# PyArango document values has wrong type after save()

Tags: python, types, arangodb, pyarango

I have an ArangoDB collection containing some documents. I need to get one of them, add or update some data and save it.

To get the document, I use `Document` `_key` field on `Collection` instance:

```
doc = collection[key]
```

Then, I update with a `dict` data:

```
for k, v in data.items():
    doc[k] = v
```

finally, I save it

```
doc.save()
```

Unfortunately some of the `int` are converted to `string`

Juste before saving:

[image]

And when I reload it with `doc2 = collection[key]`:

[image]

From what I'm seeing, I guess I could convert all `int` to `float` before saving, but it's kind of messy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out, some `int` where in fact `numpy.int64` and pyarango handle them as `string`

I simple `int(value) if isinstance(value, np.int64) else value` fixed this issue (called recursively in my case, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935278/2110805)).